# Brighthouse out of memory error

Tags: infobright

We've been using Infobright Community Edition for easily over a year now, with absolutely no trouble at all.  It's even sharing the server with a much bigger footprint database (a postgreSQL database).

Suddenly it has started giving us errors.  "Brighthouse out of memory".  I've tried increasing the ServerMainHeapSize parameter from the default 600 to 4000, and the corresponding memory parameters to the middle level size, to no avail (this is the first time I've tried to tune Infobright because it has always performed flawlessly, more or less).

Does anyone have any guess about this?  The log file simply reports the error, which no help.

On a possibly related note, several months ago, one of our tables became corrupted on the database.  The error message for that is "Error in attribute file: bad format".  This error occurs even if I try to drop the table (so it can't be dropped), or, for that matter, if I try to drop the database.  How do I drop this table?  (The data in these tables are reloaded regularly, so there are no formal backups of the Infobright database per se).

--sw

Answer (score 0):

It definately sounds to me like the table corruption has caused some issues becuase if it had been running fine without any issues before the corruption, it would seem logical.  I am the Community Manager for Infobright and I have heard of this issue as well too.  A few questions for you.

1. What version are you running?
2. How much memory does the computer have?
3. What is the OS?
4. What else is running on the computer?
5. What is the average # of connections to the instance?

Comment: 4.0.3, 32G, Red Hat EE (don't have access to the version number just now), PostgreSQL 9.1, which is by far the larger resource user, no more than 2 or 3 at any given time.